# Accessing MS-SQL Server using PHP and PhoneGap without web-services

Tags: php, sql-server, phonegap-build

I am trying to make a simple mobile application that the students needs to login and see their results set by the instructor.

However, the major issue is that the database is located on a Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (MS SQL Express 2008) .

I was thinking to run some piece of PHP code on a third-party nginx Linux Web Server that will be used for:

1. the username and password fields etc could be passed to the php file through the url
2. the php would run SQL Server queries and the response/output would be dealt with within the mobile app as text in the html.

The Nginx server is running whm/cPanel and I followed https://goo.gl/gD7WZg to enable PHP MSSQL Extension so that I can use mssql_connect rather than mysqli_connection .

Our ultimate aim is to present a pure HTML5/CSS mobile web app that processes/retreives the students exam or modules scores that is friendly with PhoneGap.

Comment: Amir, it is possible, but it is not clear how phonegap fits into this. For instance, How would the data be made available via phonegap?

Comment: I was thinking to call a cross-domain php file through HTTP to do the SQL Queries and then working with the output/input

Comment: I see I'm not being clear. Phonegap is for building mobile apps. In which case, the mobile device is more intelligent and has more resources that a web app. The major difference are the ability to use the hardware on the mobile device and the availability of more storage. As such, the traditional method of using the webview as a dumb viewer should be rethought. This means, perhaps, for this single task - of getting report of "exam or module scores" would be better as a mobile web App, and not a Phonegap. But, if learning Phonegap is a goal we can start after this message.

Comment: my goal is to have a mobile web app actually and then if I am not mistaken, I can use PhoneGap to compile it under iOS and Android, right?

Comment: Building your App, as described, is possible for both iOS and Android. But I want to be clear, this type of App should have some of the work moved to the mobile App, else you will not get into iTunes or Google Play. To be clear, one possible method is to move your query to the mobile device and send the SQL query through the network, then have that query execute on the server. --- On a typical mobile *web* App would gather information then let the PHP create the SQL query. On a phonegap App, the phonegap App creates the SQL query, then passes it to the server. A good case for a REST API.

Comment: thanks for the comments, JesseMonroy. I am not really into publishing this into the stores and just having a mobile web app is enough as long as I know how to send/retrieve data using Ajax to/from PHP (using Sqlsrv there) for example for login or populating the results table for the modules the student have.

Comment: I understand. I have a few Apps that give away and I do not think the belong in the App Store or iTunes. However, the issue is distribution. **On Android**, you can distribute the Apps by changing the Device Configuration to allow the mobile device to allow *third-party* Apps or allow *unknown sources*; it depends on the version of Android you have. **iOS** there is no choice; you MUST go through the iTunes store, and it requires a certificate and $100 paid to Apple. The sequence of doing this is beyond this thread. Please start a new thread, if you have questions on *distribution*